# Android: How do I change the style of recent queries list in a SearchView?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-styles, searchview

I implemented a recent queries Content Provider for my Searchable Configuration and it works, but how do I change the style of the list?

It came with white text on light background, I'd like to change at least the color of text.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `suggestionRowLayout` attribute from the AppCompat Lollipop’s SearchView API. For a complete list of attributes see [this post from Android Developers Blog](https://android-developers.blogspot.com.br/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html).

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="searchViewStyle">@style/AppTheme.SearchView</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.SearchView" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.SearchView">        
    <!-- Layout for query suggestion rows -->
    <item name="suggestionRowLayout">@layout/abc_search_dropdown_item_icons_2line</item>
</style>
```

If you have problems with the `suggestionRowLayout` attribute you can try the solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/26581489/1374015. Alternatively, you could try to use the old searchView* theme attributes as you can see [in this post](http://www.jayway.com/2014/06/02/android-theming-the-actionbar/).

Comment: The Android Developers Blog link is broken: it should be https://android-developers.blogspot.ca/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html